# How to define an Intent Filter to react to a Drive file pattern?

Tags: android, intentfilter

I'm trying to get my app to react to a .backup file in drive.

I defined my  Intent filter as follow

```
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/restoreAppBackup">

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.backup" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/restoreAppBackup">

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="*/*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.backup"
                android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
```

This works fine once the drive file is downloaded locally, but if I try to open it from the Drive app it doesn't react.
If I remove the scheme filter it starts to react to everything event when it doesn't match the patch pattern...

Any ideas ?

Comment: Use MIME types, not file extensions. There is no requirement that Drive, or any content- or document-publishing app, use file extensions in their `Uri` values.

Comment: This file doesn't have any mimetype. Even if I try to match the file name without using the extension it doesn't work.

Comment: "This file doesn't have any mimetype" -- and that is your problem. Choose a file extension/MIME type pair that is well-known, and you will have better luck with these files.

Comment: So there no way to just use the path pattern ?
If I call the file MyAPPBackup.xxx and uses android:pathPattern=".*MyAPPBackup.*" it cannot match ?

Comment: The path pattern will not work for apps that do not use the file extension in their `Uri` values. I repeat: there is no requirement that Drive, or any content- or document-publishing app, use file extensions in their `Uri` values.